# How do I get rid of "is not well formed" error about my .hgtags file?

Tags: mercurial

Someone accidentally mashed their l key while merging .hgtags a couple weeks ago, and we started getting messages about how `.hgtags@eed03ad8bbe7, line 1: node 'll005a7e9815cb34a143f349469b6b3c27174af7f6' is not well formed`.

I went and fixed the tags file, and everything seemed hunky dory, but now when people clone they get that message. Is there a way to turn it off? Do I have to edit history and tell everyone in the company to blow away all their repositories and re-clone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (but aren't certain) that Mercurial looks at the `.hgtags` file in all heads when parsing.  Check `hg heads` to see all heads and add a commit to each one that still has the malformed file and new cloners should be okay.  People who have their own branches that still have the malformed data in the tip will get that message until they merge the fix into their branches (be they named or anonymous/bookmark)

Disclaimer: there's a 50% chance I'm wrong about that. :)

Comment: You win! It was in a closed branch, but there was a head that still had the typo in it.